# What is the difference between Times and Dup in Assembly Language?

Tags: assembly, x86, operating-systems

In a bootloader, the second last line is :

> TIMES 510-($-$$) db 0

Now, will this command also do the same :

> db 510-($-$$) DUP (0)

If not why?

I know what `TIMES` does, but its not mentioned in my x86 book by Mazidi (Pearson Publication). Any idea why?

And what is the meaning of the `$` sign exactly? Different sites have different information about `$`.

And is the line `TIMES 510-($-$$) db 0` absolutely necessary even if my bootloader code is of 512 bytes in size?

So can anyone help me with these questions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`TIMES` and `DUP` are assembler specific commands, and as such aren't part of x86 assembly language. Same goes for `$` and `$$`.

The `$` symbol denotes the current address of the statement, and the `$$` denotes the address of the beginning of current section. So the lines with `DUP` and `TIMES` calculate the current address in the section and subtracts it from 510. This effectively just zeroes out the section from the beginning to the current address.

Comment: Okay sir, that helped a lot but will both the statements have the same output. And my book discusses about DUP and it uses MASM. Does Masm also have Times ?

Comment: @TotalAnimeImmersion I am not familiar with MASM personally, but I think checking MASM's documentation would be a good start.

Answer (score 5):

`DUP` is a specific operand specifier to the `DB`/`DW`/etc psuedo-instructions, telling them to repeat a specific value.  It can only be used in these data instructions.

`TIMES` is a generic instruction prefix, telling the assembler to produce multiple copies of the instruction (or psuedo-instruction), whatever it may be.

AFAIK, `TIMES` is specific to NASM, whereas `DUP` is widely supported.  The reason why `TIMES` is used in NASM is that one of the primary design goals of NASM was to simplify the use of directives and provide more logical, rational ways of doing things.  `TIMES` can be used in the way you show to fill a space with zeroes, but there are other applications (e.g. aligning loops by generating a sequence of `NOP` or similar instructions), and this way a single directive can handle multiple jobs.  I actually wasn't aware that `DUP` was supported in NASM at all.  I guess `DUP` was added in a later version for compatibility with MASM-style syntax; I'm not quite sure when; certainly it was quite late, with the result that the documentation doesn't report that it's available), but `TIMES` is preferred (at least by the original authors of NASM) as being a more generally useful directive.

As to the meaning of `$`, the reason for different sites having different descriptions is probably again due to the NASM/MASM distinction.  In NASM, `$` is a variable that contains the address at which the current instruction will be assembled. Note that as it is an *address*, it may be subject to relocation or otherwise changed during linking.  It therefore cannot be used in the `TIMES` instruction, whose value must be determinable at the point of assembly (it is a [critical expression](http://nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc3.html#section-3.8)).  `$$` is the address of the start of the section, so `$ - $$` is an offset, which is not subject to relocation and can therefore always be turned into a number.  In MASM, `$` has the same meaning, but there is no equivalent `$$` variable (I believe you would achieve the same things using the `WRT` operator, but it has been a while since I used MASM so I'm not sure about that).

This should allow you to work out the answer to your third question: `TIMES 510-($-$$) db 0` does nothing if `$-$$` is equal to `510` because the number of repetitions becomes 0, so if you know that your code is already 512 bytes long you do not need it.